# Validation (CSS 4.0): "-webkit-text-decoration" is not a known CSS property name

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I followed the course from Udemy The Complete ASP.NET MVC 5 Course, but when he uses bootstrap works there but it simply didn't work here I am stuck because of this error above. I already have bootstrap the latest version, jQuery the lastest version, popper.js and I have installed web essentials, some people said that you just need to install web essentials to solve the problem, but it didn't work here too.
[that's is the initial page that is doesn't work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdiYR.png)
[these are the options of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMv4w.png)

that's the problem it doesn't show exactly what should show

Comment: How does this error cause you to get stuck? It's just a vendor prefixed version of `text-decoration` for older versions of Safari, that is completely ignored by other browsers and won't cause any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

I am following the same course and in the course he is using a different version of Bootswatch, which is v3.3.6. I faced the same issue and with its looks in browser. Use the css file needed from this version of the site: https://bootswatch.com/3/. The version here is 3.4.1 but it works.